# What is the "2.0" in "Xamarin.Mac2.0" NuGet packaging target?

Tags: nuget, xamarin.mac

I am new to Xamarin and developing for a Mac. I am probably missing something obvious that is staring me in the face.

When targeting with a NuGet package, my expectation for Xamarin Mac is using "Xamarin.MacX.X" where "X.X" is a version of Xamarin Mac. If I look at .NET Standard support for Xamarin Mac, I see version 3.8 supports .NET Standard 2.0 and version 5.16 supports .NET Standard 2.1. Intuitively I should be able to use something like "Xamarin.Mac3.8" (or a variation without using ".").

Documentation and what I see in the wild target "Xamarin.Mac" or "Xamarin.Mac2.0" in packages. I have not been able to make targets like "Xamarin.Mac3.8" work, only "Xamarin.Mac" or "Xamarin.Mac2.0". So I am assuming that "Xamarin.Mac" or "Xamarin.Mac2.0" is what NuGet expects.

But what I am missing, is what is the "2.0" in "Xamarin.Mac2.0"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin.Mac2.0 represents the Unified API, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/update-xamarinmac-apps/

It was developed to enable 32-bit to 64-bit migration, so that significantly different from the initial release of Xamarin.Mac (32-bit only).

You might be able to dig more from old archives, but you really shouldn't care much as 32-bit apps now are dead with latest macOS.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help and you taking the time.